# Groovy script to establish connection to ActiveMQ

Tags: groovy, groovyshell, groovy-console

I'm new to groovy. Can anyone help me how to establish a connection to ActiveMQ through a groovy script?

That would be really helpful.

Comment: Are you using SoapUI?

Comment: Nope I'm not using SoapUI

Comment: I have OpenIDM and MySQL with ActiveMQ in between that...